# Load Class files over the network with Reflections

Tags: java, class, networking

Is there a way to use a reflection over the network like `"wwww.domain.com/codes/MyClass.Class"`

We have got a server, where we save the code, and on the other server we run the program and load different code from the first server.

Thank

Comment: This smells like _huge_ security risks, unless implemented very secure...

Comment: Isn't everything that's insecurely implemented a security risk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`URLClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dDZhWHzZ
I get:
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class Main can not access a member of class Hello with modifiers ""
 at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:65)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:349)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at Main.main(Main.java:20)

Comment: @Nicolas: I assume you've adapted the code to your domain/class names etc before trying?

Comment: Yes we did, we currently set it up to http://gamboo.at/ where we can find http://gamboo.at/Hello.class for testing. We don't get an "not found" error anymore, which is great success!

Comment: @Philipp Spieß: Double-check that the class's constructor is public.

Comment: Now it says:"Cannot acces a member of a class with modifiers "public" :D

Comment: ah. i forgot the public class. :> sorry.

Comment: Is there a way to load URLs with HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Answer (score 0):

Java provides RMI for doing what you need to do.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html

Comment: I think with RMI we'll get a performance Problem?
+ the security manager we start runs only on one of the servers?

Comment: But notice that RMI completes the operation ON the other server and gets the output rather than fetching the code from there and completing operation here. That will sure help you with respect to performance.

Comment: *Unless of course if your first server is a file hosting account :P Then you should go for `URLClassLoader`