# Java URLClassLoader with SSL

Tags: java, networking, reflection, ssl

I'm refering to this question: [Load Class files over the network with Reflections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470111/load-class-files-over-the-network-with-reflections)

We successfully loaded the class file, but i thougt, it would be better, if we could use the same thing via SSL. (https://example.com)

I tried to simply add an "s" but I get a "Class not found" exception.

Hope someone can handle that!

Comment: Could be that the web server is not listening for HTTPS (port 443), or that the SSL certificate is not valid/certified by a trusted CA. Try browse to the URL of the class in your web browser (using the `https://` URL).

Comment: ok, so we need a valid SSL for this? that should do it!